# Adding an entity to a table at Azure in Java

Tags: java, azure, azure-table-storage

I'm trying to add an entity to a table at Azure but I'm getting many errors. Here is my code:

```
package table;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.TableQuery.*;

public class tableTutorial {

 public static final String storageConnectionString=
"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;"+
"AccountName=my_storage_name;"+
"AccountKey=my_storage_account_key;"+
"EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";

public static void main (String args[]) {
try
    {
        // Retrieve storage account from connection-string.
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount =
            CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);

        // Create the table client.
        CloudTableClient tableClient = 
 storageAccount.createCloudTableClient();

        // Create a cloud table object for the table.
        CloudTable cloudTable = tableClient.getTableReference("people");

        // Create a new customer entity.
        CustomerEntity customer1 = new CustomerEntity("Harp", "Walter");
        customer1.setEmail("Walter@contoso.com");
        customer1.setPhoneNumber("425-555-0101");

        // Create an operation to add the new customer to the people table.
        TableOperation insertCustomer1 = 
      TableOperation.insertOrReplace(customer1);

        // Submit the operation to the table service.
        cloudTable.execute(insertCustomer1);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        // Output the stack trace.
        e.printStackTrace();
       }

    }

}



class CustomerEntity extends TableServiceEntity {
public CustomerEntity(String lastName, String firstName) {
    this.partitionKey = lastName;
    this.rowKey = firstName;
   }

 public CustomerEntity() { 

   String email;
   String phoneNumber;
 }
 public String getEmail() {
    return this.email;
  }

 public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
  }

  public String getPhoneNumber() {
    return this.phoneNumber;
  }

  public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
  }
}
```

The errors I'm getting are:

com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: An attempt was made to access an inaccessible member of the entity during serialization.
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.TableServiceEntity.writeEntity(TableServiceEntity.java:468)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.TableEntitySerializer.getPropertiesFromDictionary(TableEntitySerializer.java:213)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.TableEntitySerializer.writeJsonEntity(TableEntitySerializer.java:129)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.TableEntitySerializer.writeSingleEntityToStream(TableEntitySerializer.java:63)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.TableOperation.insertImpl(TableOperation.java:381)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.TableOperation.performInsert(TableOperation.java:362)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.TableOperation.execute(TableOperation.java:682)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.CloudTable.execute(CloudTable.java:529)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.CloudTable.execute(CloudTable.java:496)
    at table.tableTutorial.main(tableTutorial.java:86)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.PropertyPair cannot access a member of class table.CustomerEntity with modifiers "public"
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.newIllegalAccessException(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.PropertyPair.generateEntityProperty(PropertyPair.java:291)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.TableServiceEntity.writeEntityWithReflection(TableServiceEntity.java:211)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.TableServiceEntity.writeEntity(TableServiceEntity.java:465)

Comment: You have to have public properties in order for your class to be serializable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.PropertyPair cannot access a member of class table.CustomerEntity with modifiers "public"

To serialize your entity, your `CustomerEntity` should be public, so it should be defined in a separate file. Also note not to declare properties in constructor method.

Here's the code for you to refer.

```
package table;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.TableServiceEntity;

public class CustomerEntity extends TableServiceEntity {

public CustomerEntity(String lastName, String firstName) {
    this.partitionKey = lastName;
    this.rowKey = firstName;
}

public CustomerEntity() { }

String email;
String phoneNumber;

public String getEmail() {
    return this.email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPhoneNumber() {
    return this.phoneNumber;
}

public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}
}
```